# Как формировать названия для топиков Kafka?

Tags: стандарт, apache-kafka, именование

Существует ли выработанные практики/стандарты для именования топиков в Kafka?
Есть ли "правила хорошего тона" для этого?
В документации и имеющихся книжках не смог найти этой информации.
Предварительно предполагаю использовать camelCase.

Comment: главное тут - соглашение и единообразие внутри вашей команды/проекта, остальное вторично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жесткого стандарта нет. Если топиков планируется больше трёх или в будущем возможно появление новых, то лучше разработать принцип формирования названий.
Пример подхода: https://skalolaskovy.ru/analytics/598-kafka-topik-naming-convention